# URLConnection.getHeaderField("Content-Disposition") is not working in web application

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

I'm building that allows users to post a URL to file in a content repository which will be downloaded and uploaded to our application database. I'm trying to derive the filename from the URL using the below lines of code

```
URL url = new URL(fileUrl);
String fileName = url.getPath();
fileName = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
```

But sometimes it's not obvious that the URL will have filename in it. Hence I decided to use the header field 'Content-Disposition' to figure out the file name. I have the below code

```
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
String raw = conn.getHeaderField("Content-Disposition");
if (raw != null && raw.indexOf("=") != -1) {
String[] args = raw.split(";");
for (String arg:args) {
if (arg.trim().startsWith("filename=")) {
fileName = arg.split("=")[1];
fileName = fileName.replace("\"","");
break;
}
}
```

A sample URL that I'm using is this

> https://canvas.instructure.com/files/29736945/download?download_frd=1&verifier=9qXASsNw1GooUj572l92OiJ1kIe30jFN1RAHZlcT

This code works fine when I ran it with my unit tests. But when I deploy it in to my web application running on Jetty the request header field is not found. I'm using JMeter to fire the request to the web application. What could be wrong in here?

Comment: `Content-Disposition` is an optional field... HTTP servers don't have to send it back.

Comment: That's going to be a problem for me. Is there any other way to find out the filename given a URL to the file path?

Comment: Most content online doesn't have a filename other than the URL.  I would check for Content-Disposition first and then fall back to some other naming scheme (for example "domain-timestamp-n" or something similar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by changing the code to use download the file using HttpClient and then checking the response headers for Content-Disposition. If not found then generate a random file using the hostname and the timestamp.